# How do you execute javascript on demand

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am using jquery to build a tabs. I can switch back forth in between tabs and display/hide content based on which tab I click.

What really need is to based on which tab clicked, I need to call different javascript for each tab. I dont want to load all the javascirpts at pageload. I am using highcharts to build charts and these charts could be very heavy. I dont want to load all these javascripts on page load. I need to load javascripts based on which tabs to clicked. Any help in how could I easily accomplish this?

Right now This is what I am doing:

**this is the javascript for tabs**

```
<script>
    // Wait until the DOM has loaded before querying the document
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('ul.tabs').each(function () {
            // For each set of tabs, we want to keep track of
            // which tab is active and it's associated content
            var $active, $content, $links = $(this).find('a');

            // If the location.hash matches one of the links, use that as the active tab.
            // If no match is found, use the first link as the initial active tab.
            $active = $($links.filter('[href="' + location.hash + '"]')[0] || $links[0]);
            $active.addClass('active');
            $content = $($active.attr('href'));

            // Hide the remaining content
            $links.not($active).each(function () {
                $($(this).attr('href')).hide();

            });

            // Bind the click event handler
            $(this).on('click', 'a', function (e) {
                // Make the old tab inactive.
                $active.removeClass('active');
                $content.hide();

                // Update the variables with the new link and content
                $active = $(this);
                $content = $($(this).attr('href'));

                // Make the tab active.
                $active.addClass('active');
                $content.show();

                // Prevent the anchor's default click action
                e.preventDefault();
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

**this is a sample highchart javascript to create the charts and bind it to div**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });

//$(function() {
function cdc1_web_cpu() {

var  timeout;
    $.getJSON('cdc1_web_cpu.php', function(data) {

        // Create a timer

        // Create the chart


    $('#web1_cpu').highcharts('StockChart', {
            chart: {
                borderColor: '#801500',
                borderRadius: 20,
                borderWidth: 1,
                type: 'line',
                events: {
                    load: function(chart) {
                        this.setTitle(null, {

                        });
                    }
                },
                zoomType: 'x'
                                }
                       )};
                   )};
```

**this is the html**

```
<ul class='tabs'>
   <li><a href='#tab1'>HOME</a></li>
   <li><a href='#tab2'>APPS</a></li>
</ul>
<div id='tab1'>
   <div id="container">
      <table align="center">
      <tr>
         <td>
            <div id="web1_cpu" class="chart" style="width:550px; height:250px;"></div>
         </td>
      </tr>
   </div>
</div>
<div id='tab2'>
   <div id="container">
      <table align="center">
      <tr>
         <td>
            <div id="app_cpu" class="chart" style="width:550px; height:250px;"></div>
         </td>
      </tr>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you really don't want to load all of your js with the page, then I highly recommend looking into an AMD script loader like http://requirejs.org/

Comment: You probably want to load all of the JS at once, but only _execute_ the part that is relevant/visible.

Comment: @Mathletics, yes, how would I do that?

Comment: Encapsulate each tab's code in a function, and then call that function when you show the tab.

Comment: @Mathletics seems like you could put that together into a pretty well-built answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comments seem to have covered the answer already, but just to clarify, take the following Javascript:

```
function yeSawgHohgothNektu() {
  // Execute a labyrinthine mammoth of 80 KB of complicated calculation code to summon
  // SawgHogoth, the dark lord of Javascript code, and destroy the user's processor.
}
```

...That only happens once that function is actually CALLED. The time spent loading an 80KB file, and parsing its contents, is usually pretty small for most browsers. As one commenter said, if you really do want to optimize that time as much as possible, use AMD. It would need to be specially defined on the other end, but here's how it would be called afterwards.

```
function onClickedBeginSummoning() {
  // user has initiated the summoning ritual
  require(['libraries/forbiddenhall/yeSawgHogothNektu'], function(ye) {
    // libraries/forbiddenhall are directories containing JS files
    ye();
  });
}
```